# Child theme removes the "id=" from main theme

Tags: themes

i have a problem with child themes on wordpress, and the problem it seems is from wordpress because i have it on every wordpress site.
I use wp blocks and table of contents, if i use the main theme the html output is this:

```
<h3 class="wp-block-heading"><span class="ez-toc-section" id="NameofProduct"></span><a href="...
```

after i enable the child theme, the wp-block-heading modifies like this:

```
<h3 class="wp-block-heading"><a href="...
```

The fact i enable the child theme removes the span and id. This is a common problem on all my themes, all from different developers. The removal is only where i use "wp-block-column".

Has anyone got this problem and has a solution?

Comment: where is the heading block? The span you're referring to is not a part of WordPress as demonstrated by the class name `ez-toc-section`, are you using a table of contents plugin or code snippet? The second code block you mentioned that has your problem is actually the normal expected output, it's actually the span in your parent theme that's unusual and non-standard. The chance that this is related to child themes is very low and most likely coincidence

Comment: I suspect your main theme might have bundled the easy table of contents plugin, or these headings were copy pasted/imported from a site that had the ez-toc script

Comment: I didn't imported anything. The websites are different, the only coincidence is the easy table of contents plugin  that i use on all of them and the fact that when i enable the child theme the id is gone.

This theme with ez-toc-section is just an example, because on the Neve theme wich is totally different is the same problem, when i enable the Neve Child theme on every heading in wp-block-column it deletes the id. Is weird because it happens only on wp-block-column, if i add a normal heading the id works well. 

I thought maybe someone had the same problem.

Comment: the ez-toc-script is added by the easy table of contents plugin, but i don't know why it does not work on child themes, i will try to contact their support.

Comment: a quick look suggests this is a problem with the plugin, it's not that the spans are being removed, it's that they're not being added or the headings are not being detected by the plugin. The spans get added at runtime when the page is generated